# How do you receive a file stream in javascript and POST it using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm receiving a file using a `FORM POST` in ASP.NET and sending it back like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fStream);
Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

What I want to do at this point is take the data and then repost it using AJAX. The problem is I am trying to understand how the data should be encoded or added to the data attribute of a jQuery AJAX `POST`.

Is this even possible? Can I receive a file stream server-side, send it back as a stream (or something else), store it in a JS variable and then send it as the 'data' in a jQuery AJAX `POST`?

Comment: Maybe you could upload it in chunks? Or are you trying to upload a live video stream of some sort?

Comment: No. This is basically the test... Lets say I have two pages. One is the form, the other is what I will post the form too. When the second page receives the file - all I want to do is stream it right back as a response. Capture that in the same page that posted it. Then do another post somewhere else using that streamed data and save it. This works - but my file is corrupted. I don't think I am encoding it properly when I send it back, or I'm not dealing with it correctly in javascript when it's returned as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to upload a file using jquery AJAX.

[Uploadify](http://cjax.sourceforge.net/examples/plugin_uploadify.php)

This link can be useful for you. It is exactly same example what you want. See the code and let me know if you have any query. I have successfully implemented it in my code.

Advantages :

- It is also helpful for you if your file size is too large.
- It is easy to implement.
- AJAX.